# Predicting even bits with the universal prior

Tags: computability-theory

If the universal prior is fed a sequence where all even bits are 0 and all odd bits are drawn from some computable distribution, it will eventually become near-certain that the next 1000 even bits are 0 (according to [this page from Li and Vitanyi](http://www.ibiblio.org/weidai/temp/page332.png)).

In fact, it can still learn that if the odd bits are drawn from an uncomputable distribution (according to [this paper by Lattimore, Hutter, Gavane](http://www.hutter1.net/publ/evenbits.pdf)).

How far ahead can it learn? For example, if we give it a sequence of N bits where all even bits are 0, will it become near-certain that all even bits in the next N are also 0 (for large enough N)? Will it ever become near-certain that *all* even bits are 0?